# Angular ui.router, Creating an Optional First Path Param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Relatively new to working with Angular, but I couldn't seem to find any url aliasing or fully optional path params (something like `{/var1}/:var2` when using ui.router's `$stateProvider`.

I'm looking to have the following both be valid paths, ideally on the same state declaration so that I can call state changes using one or both params.

```
/var1/var2
/var2
```

Naturally, I can use matches like the following, but none of these are true solutions.

- `/:var1/:var2`, but this still requires an empty value for var1 (`//var2`)
- `/:var2?var1` or `/:var2/:var1?`, but neither of these are
  ideal in context as they rearrange the path.
- `/:var1/:var2` AND `/:var2` as separate states, but I'd likely need to manage state changes more closely and select based on which params are available.

Any info to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

And a quick stripped down sample for context.

`$stateProvider
    .state('app.view', {
        url : '/:var1/:var2'
    }).state('app.view2', {
        url : '/:var2'
    });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this would work

```
.state('app.view', {
    url: '/:var1/:var2',
    templateUrl: 'yourTpl.html',
    controller: 'YourCtrl',
    params: {
        var1: {squash: true, value: null}
    }
})
```

squash configures how a default parameter value is represented in the URL when the current parameter value is the same as the default value

Comment: Awesome, squash does exactly what I was looking to accomplish. Thanks a bunch.