# ui-router of angularjs optional parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('signup', {
        url:'/app/signup/:ref',
        templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
      })
```

Above is my route config using ui-route. It works when I visit `localhost:80/signup/something`

but I also want it to work when I visit just `localhost:80/signup`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is right, the parameters could be optional.

You can also use `squash`:

```
.state('signup', {
    url: '/app/signup/:ref',
    templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
    params: {
        ref: {squash: true, value: null}
    }
})
```

squash configures how a default parameter value is represented in the URL when the current parameter value is the same as the default value

see more here: [Angular ui.router, Creating an Optional First Path Param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930529/angular-ui-router-creating-an-optional-first-path-param/38930677#38930677)

Comment: Wow, I never saw this mentioned in the docs. I think only ref should have a colon in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You have another state with that url:

```
.state('another-state', {
  url: '/app/signup',
  templateUrl: 'partials/signup2.html'
})
```

That should make your localhost:80/signup work as you require.