# How to have an optional parameter in Angular UI-Router v 1.+

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In an older version (0.4?) of angular ui-router we could do this...

`url: '/:optional'`

And everything worked fine (minus an extra backslash in the url). But when I upgraded to 1.0.5 I see...

`Error: Param values not valid for state 'projects.list'. Invalid params: [ optional ]`

I tried...

`url: '/{mine:(?:/[^/]+)?}'` too but it didn't work either

Is there a way I can do this in the 1.0 world?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38930677/3701009) to a similar question.

Also, as [stated in the UI Router's documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters):

> Route parameters with regular expressions can't be optional or greedy

Comment: According to the [same documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-in-links)  re `/:conditionId` or `/{conditionId}` syntax;  in the case `ui-sref="contacts.detail({contactId: id})"`; "The value for `id` can be anything in scope." *Unless `id` is undefined!*